# Bootstrap 3 sticky left sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not that familiar with [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I have been stuck for a day now just trying to create a sticky sidebar. Currently I'm having a sub navigation bar that is using [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) of bootstrap here is sample:

Top navigation bar

```
<div id="top-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BiddingTool</a>

        <div class="navbar-text">
            <ul class="navbar-nav list-inline">
                <li><a href="#" style="margin-left: 5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i> Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="margin-left: 20px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Database</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div><!-- /.Navigation Bar -->
```

Lower navigation bar

```
<!-- Lower Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar-xs">
<div id="lower-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Labor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tint"></i> Material</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Equipment</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
</div><!-- /.Lower Navigation Bar -->
```

I used this in my CSS:

```
.affix { top: 50px; width:100%; }
```

and in JS

```
$('.navbar-lower').affix({
  offset: {top: 50}
});
```

And here is my working example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xEc3/)

My question is **how can I make a sticky sidebar using panel of bootstrap?**

Comment: are you sure it is working? cause i don't see your fiddle working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Did you scroll it down to see the effect of the sub-navbar?

Comment: i'm using FF and it doesn't work. please make sure you support all Chrome, FF and as well as IE 9 in all circumstances

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Just want to ask what do you guys mean that it doesn't work? I'm using Chrome 34 and FF 28 and its working for me. The horizontal scroll don't exist in my application. I just did post some code in the fiddle for you guys to visualize what I'm looking for.

Comment: Deleted fiddles :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5xEc3/1/

For your sidebar Div I have made it like this...

`<div id="sidebar" class="panel panel-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="400">`

`data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="400"` are where the magic is.  You have to position it how you want with CSS now.

Comment: Its quite buggy when I scroll it down and up.

Comment: please check! it is not compatible with FF as i can see: 2 scrollbars and a full widthed affix

Comment: @newbie No it works fine, you must supply your own CSS positioning, the Affix functionality works perfectly